# Trouble in using camera with Opencv3.2 on VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, visual-studio-2015, computer-vision

[The result while running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVziz.jpg)
I began to learn Opencv recently and I chosed Opencv3.2 and VS2017. 
It seems that the camera of PC opens well, but cannot show anything in the window.My code is as follows. Please help me with problem, thanks a lot!

Today I compiled Opencv3.2 source code using cMake for VS2017 x64_Debug and x86_release, and I found that when it ran in x86_release this problem didn't occur any more, while in x64_debug it remained the same situation.
So I wonder whether there has been any problem with my win10(on MacBook) system?(I worry about the system because I've also encountered some problems causing compiling unsuccessfully, and finally I used another computer to compile the source code)
So what should I do now?

```
#include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    VideoCapture cam(0);
    Mat frame;
    if (!cam.isOpened()) { printf("Wrong!\n"); }
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            cam >> frame;
            namedWindow("test", 1);
            if (!frame.empty())
            {
                imshow("test", frame);
            }
            //waitKey(30);
            if (waitKey(30) ==27) break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The code seems fine.  How did you install OpenCV?  Did you compile from source or did you install pre-compiled headers?

Comment: See this issue in github and see if some of the suggestions help you: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8677

Comment: @rayryeng I just downloaded the pack from Opencv's website and didn't compile from source, is it necessary?

Comment: No don't think so. I'm inclined to believe it's something to do with windows. Check out the link that the other commenter sent to you.

Comment: @TFreitas Actually I tried to unistall some updates of windows as the link suggested, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: In windows definitions do you have the camera privacy options blocked?

Comment: @TFreitas No,I checked it on